# MATLAB user defined function file as fittype

Tags: matlab, function, file

I have a function saved as a 'calculateResults.m' in which the function 'ode45' is nested:

```
function y = calculateResults (concV, ksV, xTrace)
options = odeset('NonNegative', [1:size(concV,2)], 'RelTol', 1e-6, 'AbsTol', 1e-12);
[x,y] = ode45(@(t, cY)odeSet(t, cY, ksV), xTrace, concV, options);
```

I would like to use this function as a fittype:

```
ft = fittype('calculateResults( concV, ksV, x )','independent',{'x'});
```

But doing this causes the error:

> Error using fittype/testCustomModelEvaluation (line 12)
>       Expression calculateResults( concV, ksV, x ) is not a valid MATLAB expression, has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot
>       be evaluated:
>       Error in fittype expression ==> calculateResults( concV, ksV, x )
>       ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

My aim is to vary the values of 'concV' in order to fit the function 'calculateResults.m' to some data (x and y):

```
mdl = fit( x, y, ft);
```

And finally return the values of concV that best fit the data:

```
concVCalc = mdl.Coefficients.Estimate;
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Well, the error is rather clear. Somewhere an index exceeds matrix dimensions. Have you already tracked down where that happens?

Comment: @Adriaan Evaluating y = calculateResults(concV, ksV, x); independently works fine -suggesting I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Perhaps my syntax is wrong, but I have checked this against the MathWorks example.

Comment: I would try specifying the types of ALL the variables in the expression.  You need to tell fit how to interpret `concV` and `ksV`.  Looks like `concV` is a "coefficient", and `ksV` is a "problem" variable?

Comment: @Peter I tried ft = fittype('calculateResults( concV, ksV, x )','independent',{'x'},'coefficient',{'concV'},'problem',{'ksV'}); but the same error persists.

Comment: Adriaan is right.  It actually gives you the error, saying that an index exceeds matrix dimensions.  Set the debugger to stop on errors, and inspect the values inside calculateResults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by giving the coefficients as individual variables rather than an array:

```
  ft = fittype('calculateResultsForFit(x,concV1,concV2,concV3,concV4,concV5,concV6,concV7,concV8,concV9,concV10,concV11,concV12,concV13,concV14,concV15,concV16,concV17,concV18,concV19,concV20)');

    mdl = fit( x', yToFit', ft,'StartPoint',[concV1,concV2,concV3,concV4,concV5,concV6,concV7,concV8,concV9,concV10,concV11,concV12,concV13,concV14,concV15,concV16,concV17,concV18,concV19,concV20],'Lower',zeros(1,20));
```

Variable ksV now defined inside the function being fitted.